# Custom Initializer Variable for Rails Tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a custom initializer that configures a 'cloud' storage provider (Google, AWS, Rackspace). I'm creating an app that I want to be deployable by a variety of developers (using different storage providers) and I would like to be able to test each cloud provider individually. Currently I go through my initializer file three times and comment / uncomment each provider before running `rake test`. Is it possible to pass in an option to `rake test` that I can then use in my initializer for control flow (i.e. load a specific initializer)? Something like:

```
rake test --attached aws
rake test --attached google
rake test --attached rackspace
```

Here is what my initializer looks like:

```
# config/initializers/attached.rb

Attached::Attachment.options[:medium] = :aws
Attached::Attachment.options[:credentials] = "#{Rails.root}/config/aws.yml"

Attached::Attachment.options[:medium] = :google
Attached::Attachment.options[:credentials] = "#{Rails.root}/config/google.yml"

Attached::Attachment.options[:medium] = :rackspace
Attached::Attachment.options[:credentials] = "#{Rails.root}/config/rackspace.yml"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using env-vars for that.

```
$ ATTACHED="aws" rake test
```

and then

```
# config/initializers/attached.rb

attached = ENV['ATTACHED'] || "aws"

case attached
when "aws"
  Attached::Attachment.options[:medium] = :aws
  Attached::Attachment.options[:credentials] = "#{Rails.root}/config/aws.yml"
...
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if it is possible to specify an environment variable for a single execution?

Comment: The example above is exactly for a single execution.